# Can't pip install psycopg2 on windows

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2

When I try to install psycopg2, using PIP in a virtual environment, on Windows 8 I get the following error:

```
c:\python27\include\pyconfig.h(231) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include   file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory

error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I had previously had this error:

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

So I followed the various answers in this question:

and managed to get rid of

```
 error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

but have this new one to contend with

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the [psycopg website](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html), you're supposed to install it using the Windows port:

- http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

I'm guessing you'll need a version of Visual Studio installed for pip to be able to compile the headers correctly.

Comment: thanks but I still get the same error after installing from stickpeople and I don't really want to buy Visual Studio - I have installed vcsetup.exe which I thought gave me the compiler based on the other thread?

Comment: I just installed the Python 3.4 version of psycopg from the "stick people" website on Windows 7 and it imported just fine for me.